# nothing happens on trying to dismiss popover viewcontroller Swift

Tags: swift

I have a viewcontroller that is presented as popover when the user clicks on an ImageView.
The problem is, I added a button to dismiss it but when I tap on it nothing happens.
The code I have is:

```
 @IBAction func onCloseTapped(_ sender: Any) {
presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I've also tried `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` and other methods, but still nothing.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:** Posting a screenshot:
[image]

**Edit 2:** I'm presenting it from the storyboard. I've added a gesture recognizer on the image, then added segue from the storyboard that says present as popover, then anchor to the image.

Comment: How was the controller presented? Have you verified that the `onCloseTapped` method is actually being called?

Comment: i'm presenting it whren the user tap on an image. then i've placed a button and noting happens on tap on it, the code is the same from above.

Comment: I'm not asking when you show but how you show. [Edit] your question with relevant code showing how you display the controller you are unable to dismiss.

Comment: i've edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

it won't work because when you show as popover, the viewController doesn't have the navigationController. You have to create a delegate method and use the dismiss function on the viewController that make the call to the popover.

Here an exemple:

make the popover delegate, in the popover viewController:

```
protocol PopoverViewControllerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func dismiss()
}
```

then you create a delegate variable and call when the button is tapped:

```
var delegate: PopoverViewControllerDelegate?

@IBAction func onCloseTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.dismiss()
}
```

Now in the viewController that call the popover you override the prepare for segue method to set the popover delegate:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "popover" {
            if let vc = segue.destination as? PopoverViewController {
                vc.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you just need to use the delegate to dismiss your popover viewController:

```
extension ViewController: PopoverViewControllerDelegate {
    func dismiss() {
        navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to put the identifier for you segue, the identifier that we use is this = "popover"

Hope that help you.